# SQL Server query where distinct won't work - to select only unique records - and looking only at one column for uniqueness

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query where I am fetching records from a SQL Server database table that stores all of the products that users on our site has looked at (`ProductRecentlyViewed` table).

I am trying to select only the records that have unique `rv.productvariantid` (I want it to return only one of each product variant that the user has looked at).

I have tried using the keyword `DISTINCT` but since I also need the `DateCreated` for the orderby and since this is different among the records with the same `rv.productvariantid`, I cannot use `DISTINCT`.

What can I do instead to get the 20 newest unique product variants that the user has looked at? Here is my current SQL query which selects all the product variants that the user has looked at - and unfortunately it shows them more than once if the user did look at them more than once.

```
SELECT TOP 20
    rv.productId,
    p.productNameNO as productName,
    picid,
    picurl,
    rv.productRecentlyViewedId,
    rv.dateCreated,
    rv.lang,
    rv.isUserLoggedIn,
    rv.userId,
    rv.productVariantId
FROM 
    ProductRecentlyViewed rv
INNER JOIN 
    Product AS p ON rv.productid = p.productid
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         productid,
         picurl,
         picid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY isfrontpic DESC) rn
     FROM 
         productpic) c ON c.rn = 1
                       AND rv.productId = c.productId
WHERE 
    rv.lang = 'NO'
    AND rv.cookieId = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '1f102c74-278b-430e-8129-1261dfc7e2ac')
ORDER BY 
    rv.dateCreated
```

Comment: White space and line breaks really make your code readable. Please do consider **good** use of them. I've formatted your SQL for you.

Comment: Also, what is ` CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'123')` meant to be? `'123'` isn't a valid `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: Thanks for the codeformatting. I have now changed the identifier to a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing the filtering like this:

```
SELECT rv.productId, p.productNameNO as productName,
       pp.picid, pp.picurl,
       rv.productRecentlyViewedId, rv.dateCreated, rv.lang,
       rv.isUserLoggedIn, rv.userId, rv.productVariantId
FROM (SELECT TOP (20) rv.*
      FROM (SELECT rv.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rv.cookieId, rv.productId ORDER BY rv.dateCreated DESC) as seqnum
            FROM ProductRecentlyViewed rv
            WHERE rv.lang = 'NO' AND
                  rv.cookieId = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '1f102c74-278b-430e-8129-1261dfc7e2ac')
           ) rv
      WHERE seqnum = 1
     ) rv JOIN 
    Product p
    ON rv.productid = p.productid OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP (1) pp.*
     FROM productpic pp
     WHERE pp.productid = p.productid
     ORDER BY pp.isfrontpic DESC
    ) pp
ORDER BY rv.dateCreated;
```

This gives the optimizer more options for making the query faster.  In particular, it does not multiply all the rows out and then determine the first picture for each row.

Instead, it finds the 20 rows and then gets the picture for each one.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your query is giving me a couple of errors though:

Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. (the order by is frontpic desc line)
Can you help fix that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Gordon, I really like your solution. I am just not sure how to fix the two errors that I described. Can you help me out?

Comment: @NickDeveloper . . . I fixed those problems (I think).

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the update to your solution - it works perfectly. I was wondering if you could help show me where one more join should be placed in your code? LEFT JOIN ProductVariant pv ON productVariantId = rv.productVariantId  - If I want to add this after the join product.

Comment: @NickDeveloper . . . You would add `LEFT JOIN` after `pp` on the `OUTER APPLY`.

Answer (score 2):

First, select all records within the subquery, and then filter by `rn=1`

```
SELECT TOP 20 q.*
  FROM (SELECT rv.productId,
               p.productNameNO as productName,
               picid,
               picurl,
               rv.productRecentlyViewedId,
               rv.dateCreated,
               rv.lang,
               rv.isUserLoggedIn,
               rv.userId,
               rv.productVariantId,
               pv.productVariantName,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rv.productid ORDER BY c.isfrontpic DESC) rn 
          FROM ProductRecentlyViewed rv
         INNER JOIN Product as p
            ON rv.productid = p.productid
          LEFT JOIN productpic c
            ON rv.productId = c.productId
          LEFT JOIN ProductVariant pv
            ON productVariantId = rv.productVariantId 
         WHERE rv.lang = 'NO'
           AND rv.cookieId = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '123')) q
 WHERE q.rn = 1
 ORDER BY q.dateCreated
```

The grouping is performed by `PARTITION BY productid`, and get only one `productid` from each group by `rn=1`

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer - If I also need the ProductVariantName from the ProductVariant table - How can I add that as well? I have the productVariantId in the productrecentlyviewed table but where do I do the SELECT productVariantName from ProductVariant WHERE productVariantId = rv.productVariantId ? –

Comment: Also I get this error at the line "order by datecreated": Invalid column name 'dateCreated'.

Comment: it comes from `rv.dateCreated` in the subquery @NickDeveloper

Comment: Thanks I changed the order by to q.dateCreated. But now this line WHERE q.rn = 1 is giving me the error: Invalid column name 'rn'.

Comment: excuse me I left within the subquery aliased as `c`, now I fixed @NickDeveloper

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Do I need to add an index to make it perform better?

Comment: you're welcome @NickDeveloper . Of course indexes on the columns of join conditions would help, but should be tested by explain plans and cost values contained within them.